# get value from an input field in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to make a form validator for a `inputfield`. I try to get the input value from it using the `getElementById().value` method. But when I console log the variable is empty. I tried to convert my variable into a string, it doesn't solve the problem.
When I type some extra text, the counter next to it increases. But no worthy value showed. How come it's not showing the right input value? thanks!

[image]

code of my validator:

```js
const newName = document.getElementById('name');
let newNameValue = document.getElementById('name').value;

let beerArrayNames = this.state.beerArrayName;
newName.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  console.log('test ' + newNameValue);


  if (beerArrayNames.includes(newNameValue)) {
    newName.setCustomValidity('This already exist!');
  } else {
    newName.setCustomValidity('');
  }
});
```

```html
<p>Name: <input type='text' id='name' name='name' placeholder='fill in the name' required/> </p>
```

Comment: Where are you using this in React? Do you have sample code of how it's applied? The containing class for example?

Comment: @EdwinDelRio I'm coding an react.js app but need a validtion to check if the input value name is already used in my back end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fetch value using `event.target.value`.

```
newName.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  console.log('test ', event.target.value);

});
```

Working [`plunker`](https://plnkr.co/edit/DMhserw0uNlxQsGe2C3f?p=preview)

Answer (score 4):

Even though this question has an accepted answer already, I think it's important to note that a solution more in line with React's design principles would be to not directly retrieve elements in the DOM and attach event listeners to them.

Instead, you can define an `onChange` prop for the input element, which when triggered validates the input (and most likely update some UI state to show/hide error messages).

A good example of how to use of `onChange` exists in the [forms documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your variable inside your event listener (I commented out the other stuff because it doesn't work and is not part of your question)

```
newNameValue = this.value;
```

```js
const newName = document.getElementById('name');
let newNameValue;

//let beerArrayNames = this.state.beerArrayName;
newName.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  newNameValue = this.value;
  console.log('test ' + newNameValue);


  //if (beerArrayNames.includes(newNameValue)) {
    //newName.setCustomValidity('This already exist!');
  //} else {
    //newName.setCustomValidity('');
  //}
});
```

```html
<p>Name: <input type='text' id='name' name='name' placeholder='fill in the name' required/> </p>
```